# Java Nimbus Look and Feel per component customization ("Nimbus.Overrides") - other instances affected too

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am new to **Java Nimbus Look and Feel**. I am trying to use the ability of Nimbus to **customize individual component instances** using `putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides)`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/package-summary.html

I have encountered the following problem (bug?):

**"Nimbus.Overrides" value unfortunately affects apparently not only the component object to which it is explicitely set, but other objects too.**

It seems that the customized properties are "inherited" somehow to other (later "styled", apparently not previously) instances of the same type. I need to ensure that the changes are made only to one individual instance (without affecting any other objects). Example - `JButton` used, but the same problem encountered with e.g. `JTabbedPane` and custom painters:

- `button 1` - property A (content margins) customized.
- `button 2` - only property B (font) customized - but change in property A visible too (bigger manrgins), "somehow inherited" from `button 1`.
- `button 3` - no property customized (empty property map used) - both changes (A+B) seem to be inherited (bigger margins, bigger font) from `button1` and `button2`
- `button 4` - default look o JButton (no customization)

  ```
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import java.awt.Font;
  import java.awt.Insets;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.UIDefaults;


  public class NimbusPerComponentTest extends JFrame {

  public NimbusPerComponentTest()  {
      super("Test");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      // 4 buttons to test
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
      JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
      JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
      JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
      add(button1);
      add(button2);
      add(button3);
      add(button4);
      pack();

      // style        
      // button 1
      UIDefaults overrides1 = new UIDefaults();
      overrides1.put("Button.contentMargins", new Insets(10,10,10,10));        
      button1.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides1);
      // button 2
      UIDefaults overrides2 = new UIDefaults();        
      overrides2.put("Button.font", new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
      button2.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides2);
      // button 3
      UIDefaults overrides3 = new UIDefaults();
          // nothing = left empty
      button3.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides3);
      // button 4
      // no styling        

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {        
      try {
          for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
              if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                  javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                  break;
              }
          }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NimbusPerComponentTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }       
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              new NimbusPerComponentTest().setVisible(true);
          }
      });
  }
  }
  ```

[image]

Any idea WHY? What am I missing? Any elegant workarounds?
(Java 8, Windows 10)

**EDIT**

After inspiration by some of the answers:

Tried reseting the lookandfeel in the end of my original code (to null and back to Nimbus again, incl. SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI), and the only result:

now even the button4 is painted wrong (with both margins and font changed) although the universal defaults were never touched... Weird.

**EDIT 2**

I managed to find a **single line workaround /hack**. See my own answer to my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a long time of debugging,  it seems that I have managed to find a **single line workaround / hack** which might also suggest the cause of the problem:

Immediately after styling each component with `putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides)` you can prevent "inheriting" the properties to subsequently styled components by this code:

```
button1.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides1);
UIManager.getDefaults().putDefaults(new Object[0]); 
  // add after each "styling"
  // - clears the compiledDefaults in NimbusLookAndFeel
```

What it does?

Functionally, nothing (empy array = nothing put), but it fires PropertyChange event (see source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/UIDefaults.java#UIDefaults.putDefaults%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)), which is listened in `DefaultsListener` private class in `NimbusLookAndFeel` class (see source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/NimbusLookAndFeel.java#NimbusLookAndFeel.DefaultsListener.propertyChange%28java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent%29)), which was the only way I managed to find **to clear the `compiledDefaults`** cache (?) in `NimbusLookAndFeel`, which - as it seems to me - is causing the problem:

```
if ("UIDefaults".equals(key)) {
    compiledDefaults = null;
}
```

I noticed the problem during debugging in `getDefaultsForPrefix` method (using the `compiledDefaults`) in `NimbusLookAndFeel` class - see source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/NimbusLookAndFeel.java#NimbusLookAndFeel.getDefaultsForPrefix%28java.lang.String%29). **For later components, it was returning not only "real defaults", but for some reason also the custom properties set to the previous component.**

To make it clear: I am a total amateur and have no detailed knowledge or understanding of the Nimbus classes details or architecture. I may be wrong, but the solutions works for me...

[image]

Is it unsuitable for some reason? Any risks? Is it really a bug?

One problem:

I noticed that if I `pack()` my frame **not before** styling the components with putClientProperty (as in my code in my question), but **after**, the solution does not work (nothing helps)...

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me if I alter the creation of the `UIDefaults`. Instead of

```
UIDefaults overrides1 = new UIDefaults();
```

I used

```
UIDefaults overrides1 = (UIDefaults) UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().clone();
```

Do this for `overrides2` and `overrides3` as well:

```
    // style
    // button 1
    UIDefaults overrides1 = (UIDefaults) UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().clone();
    overrides1.put("Button.contentMargins", new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    button1.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides1);
    // button 2
    UIDefaults overrides2 = (UIDefaults) UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().clone();
    overrides2.put("Button.font", new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    button2.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides2);
    // button 3
    UIDefaults overrides3 = (UIDefaults) UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().clone();
    // nothing = left empty
    button3.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides3);
    // button 4
    // no styling
```

This produces the following output on my machine:

[image: Screenshot with my modifications]

Please note that the size of the `UIDefaults` created this way may be quite big.

Comment: This is one solution, but it should not be necessary.  The documentation clearly states that the override UIDefaults is supposed to be merged with the look-and-feel’s defaults.

Comment: Yes, this answer might work (not tested yet),  but it cancels the whole point of overriding just some selected properties and having it merged with the default ones. Copying the whole map of default properties to each individual component must be really quite espensive...

Comment: @VGR yes, but this is exactly what does not work as expected/documented, see my example

Comment: When I wrote my answer I assumed there is a bug in Nimbus (@VGR thanks for digging into the source), still I felt I should provide a workaround. That is what my answer tries to describe.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to a bug in the `shouldUpdateStyleOnEvent` method of javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel.  From [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/NimbusLookAndFeel.java#NimbusLookAndFeel.shouldUpdateStyleOnEvent%28java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent%29):

```
protected boolean shouldUpdateStyleOnEvent(PropertyChangeEvent ev) {
    String eName = ev.getPropertyName();

    // These properties affect style cached inside NimbusDefaults (6860433)
    if ("name" == eName ||
        "ancestor" == eName ||
        "Nimbus.Overrides" == eName ||
        "Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults" == eName ||
        "JComponent.sizeVariant" == eName) {

        JComponent c = (JComponent) ev.getSource();
        defaults.clearOverridesCache(c);
        return true;
    }

    return super.shouldUpdateStyleOnEvent(ev);
}
```

Needless to say, that is not a valid way to compare Strings.  I haven’t been able to find anything in the bug database about this; perhaps later when I have time, I’ll submit a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. May be I did this wrong, but I tried to debug this method in my NetBeans and in my example in all cases the condition was evaluated true (i.e. correct) for the given strings (in spite of the wrong comparison code), i.e. clearOverridesCache appeared to be run.

Comment: It seems that the problem might be in another "cache" - see my own answer to my question...